# Two threads updating in CopyOnWriteArrayList

Tags: multithreading, copyonwritearraylist

Two thread Lets suppose t1 and t2 both trying to perform update operation in copyOnWriteArrayList at same time ......then which thread changes will get copied in original list first?

Comment: The one that gets the lock first.

Comment: @StephenC what if two threads getting lock at the same time(actually some one asked this question but not sure , whether this scenario ever occurs or not)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this scenario, the two threads will attempt ... simultaneously ... to acquire the write lock on the `CopyOnWriteArrayList`.  One thread will get the lock immediately.  The other thread will be blocked until the thread that got the lock releases it.

> What if two threads get the lock at the same time.

Two threads can *attempt* to get a lock at the same time.  However, only one thread will get the lock immediately.  The other will be blocked.  This is a *fundamental invariant* of locks.  The instruction sequences used to acquire and release locks ... and ultimately the CPU hardware *guarantee* that the invariant is not violated.